# JavaFX media volume bindings

Tags: javafx, properties, binding, media, volume

I am working on small game in JavaFX.
I have an utility class to manage music:

```
private static Map<SongEnum, Media> songs = new EnumMap<>(SongEnum.class);
private static MediaPlayer currentSong;
public static void playSong(SongEnum song) {
    if(songs == null && currentSong != null) {
        currentSong.stop();
        currentSong = null;
    }
    Media media = songs.get(song);
    if(media == null) {
        String path = ApplicationUtils.class.getResource(song.getPath()).toExternalForm();
        media = new Media(path);
        songs.put(song, media);
    }
    if(currentSong != null) {
        if(currentSong.getMedia() == media)
            return;
        currentSong.stop();
    }
    currentSong = new MediaPlayer(media);
    currentSong.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    currentSong.play();
}
```

I want to be able to play many different songs - is above approach correct?
Also I am not sure how to implement volume-management system in this case. My first thought was to bind some slider property (which lies in another class) with MediaPlayer property, but in this case it will change everytime the songs changes. So, what is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In the game we're currently working on, we just used the volume property of the MediaPlayer. We put `0.3` on the background theme, and `0.8`or `1`on effects as they should be higher than the background theme. Test it out see how it works best by using `currentSong.setVolume("0 to 1");`. As of using a slider, why don't just use a `setOnEndOfMedia`to loop the song. With this, the volume shouldn't change. This only works if you of course are only looping the same song.

```
currentSong.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
        currentSong.seek(Duration.ZERO);
        currentSong.play();
    });
```

If not, I would add make `currentSong static`, and then access it like `"YourMediaClass.currentSong.setVolume("slider.getSliderValue or whatever you use")`. This is probably what you're looking for.